# how to add custom hyphenated words to spellchecker in LibreOffice?

Tags: spell-checking, libreoffice

I use LibreOffice for editing medical research articles. LibreOffice has 3 types of dictionaries: spelling, hyphenation, and thesaurus. A lot of proteins, genes, devices, etc, have hyphenated names. Bcl-2 should pass spellcheck, Bcl should not. However, if I just add Bcl-2 to my custom medical dictionary, it doesn't pass and continues to complain about Bcl. Even if I reduce the minimum hyphenation character count from 5 to 3, it still puts red ink under Bcl, missing the fact that Bcl-2 is valid.

Apparently I can have all the custom dictionaries I want, but only one hyphenation dictionary at a time. Any idea how I can add words to Libhyphen hyphenator or some other way to resolve this?

Comment: Thats a bummer, but the issue is not related to programming, which this Q&A site is about. Think this question is better fitted elsewhere. superuser.com could probably do.

Comment: Hello from 2021, Niels! Have you found the answer?